# tOGGLE cASE For Textbox?

Tags: vb.net

How can I add tOGGLE cASE to textboxes, for example, I click a button and it changes the text in a textbox to tOGGLE cASE (hello -> hELLO), basically it takes first letter and lower cases it and the rest upper cases it.

Comment: Don't downvote without any reason. If you do so, provide one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a method using .NET Culture functions to first convert to Title Case and then invert the case to your "tOGGLE cASE"

```
Private Sub btn_ConvertTotOGGLEcASE_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_ConvertTotOGGLEcASE.Click

    'Get the current value of the textbox
    Dim MyText As String = MyTextBox.Text

    'Convert it to Title Case using built in .NET tools
    Dim MyTextInfo As System.Globalization.TextInfo = New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US", False).TextInfo
    MyText = MyTextInfo.ToTitleCase(MyText)

    'Then invert the case of all the characters
    Dim InvertedText As Char() = MyText.Select(Function(c) If(Char.IsLetter(c), If(Char.IsUpper(c), Char.ToLower(c), Char.ToUpper(c)), c)).ToArray()

    'Finally convert it back to a string
    MyTextBox.Text = New String(InvertedText)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split you string in an array, iterate in the array with lcase(mid(string,1,1) & ucase(mid(string,2, len(string)-1)), and recompose your array in a string

```
Public function ToogleText(myStr as string) as string

  dim str() as string  
  str = split(myStr," ")
  dim toogleStr as string
  toogleStr = ""

  for each substr as string in str
       toogleStr = toogleStr & lcase(mid(substr,1,1)) & ucase(mid(substr, 2,len(substr)-1)) & "  "
   next substr
    if len(toogleStr) > 0 then
        ToogleText =  mid(toogleStr,1,len(toogleStr)-1)
   else
        ToogleText =""

   end if

end function
```

Comment: The errors are coming from the text right and left, anyway to fix it?

Comment: forgot vb.net don't have left and right function, use mid then

Comment: I'm getting this error Warning 1 Function 'ToogleText' doesn't return a value on all code paths. A null reference exception could occur at run time when the result is used. Also, code function doesnt work

Comment: If it's only that, you can correct that, it just mean that the if doesn't have an else.

Comment: It worked, although when you press the button twice the program crashes. An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll Additional information: Argument 'Length' must be greater or equal to zero.